# Sql server tables not visible

Tags: sql-server

some tables in a sql server database are not visible any more. I know they are there, because they are being used by an application. What could have caused this? and more's to the point what can I do to see them again?

The tables all have the dbo schema.  I can see the rest of the dbo tables, but four of them have gone missing.

Comment: Which tables can't you see?

Comment: I've solved the problem, I was using an earlier version of the database.  I feel so stupid now, I think I'll just go and stand in a corner.

Comment: Just as a by the bye though, is it wise to mix schemas in a database?

Comment: No, I think that will result in trouble.

Comment: @GeorgeWilliams In SQL Server it is entirely appropriate to have more than one schema in a database. The meaning of schema differs between SQL Server and Oracle. In SQL Server security is often assigned via schema for example.